# How to create undo using Snackbar in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to create undo function using Snackbar in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter when "Delete" option is clicked.
I have achieved my goal to create Undo function using Snackbar but my main aim is to show item deleted from **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter** and when undo is clicked I want that deleted item to be back in **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**. How can I do that? Please help me !

> Here's my code of **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter** class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ExpenseModel, MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    GoogleSignInAccount account;
    Context context;
    int calendarClick,
            beerClick,
            rentClick,
            bikeClick,
            groceryClick,
            foodClick = 0;

    String whichCategorySelected;
    boolean isCategorySelected = false;
    String expenseType = "";
    String updateDate = "";
    String stopDelete = "";



    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ExpenseModel> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position, @NonNull ExpenseModel model) {
        account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
        setDatabaseReference(account);
        holder.expenseItem.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.expenseAmount.setText("Rs. " + model.getAmount());
        holder.expenseDate.setText(model.getTime());
        holder.category.setText(model.getExType());

        //show update dialog when clicked on recycler view item and
        //delete the selected item from recycler view
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int timeSnackBar = 5000;

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("Edit");
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete");
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete all");
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Edit")) {
                            calendarClick = 0;
                            expenseType = model.getExType();
                            showUpdateDialog(view, model.getDescription(), model.getAmount(), model.getTime(), position);
                        } else if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {

                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Item is being deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            stopDelete = "STOP";
                                        }
                                    }).setDuration(timeSnackBar);
//                            snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                            Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

                            snackbarLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                            snackbar.show();
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (!stopDelete.equals("STOP")) {
                                        databaseReference.child(Objects.requireNonNull(getRef(holder.getLayoutPosition()).getKey()))
                                                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            stopDelete = "";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }else {
                                        stopDelete = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            }, timeSnackBar);


                        } else {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                    .setTitle("Alert")
                                    .setMessage("Are you sure delete everything ?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            getDatabaseReference(account).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "All expenses deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Something went wrong. Please check your internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                                    .show();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView expenseItem, expenseAmount, expenseDate, category;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            expenseItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerItemView);
            expenseAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerAmountView);
            expenseDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDateView);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no error in this code. The onle feature i want to add is : when item on recyclerView is deleted is should show some deleted animation and should remove from list. But when users click on "UNDO" button snackbar, deleted item should come back in same position including animation.